# pooler error: query_wait_timeout in pgbouncer logs

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I am getting  `pooler error: query_wait_timeout` for different databases in the pgbouncer log 6 to 7 times a day . When the error occurs for masterdata database , it gives me a timeout in the application.

The configuration is below :

```
  default_pool_size: 10
  max_client_conn: 5000
  max_db_connections: 400
  min_pool_size: 0
  pool_mode: "transaction"
  reserve_pool_size: 20
  reserve_pool_timeout: 1
  query_timeout: 0
  ignore_startup_parameters: "search_path, extra_float_digits"
  server_reset_query: "DISCARD ALL"
  server_reset_query_always: 1
```

As the query timeout is disabled (`query_timeout:0`) and the `pool_mode` is set to `transaction`, why am I still having this error? Do I need to set some `min_pool_size` for my masterdata database to eliminate the above error?

Comment: query_timeout and query_wait_timeout are different settings.  You are looking at the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#query_wait_timeout) says:

> #### query_wait_timeout
>
> Maximum time queries are allowed to spend waiting for execution. If the query is not assigned to a server during that time, the client is disconnected. 0 disables. If this is disabled, clients will be queued indefinitely. [seconds]
>
> This setting is used to prevent unresponsive servers from grabbing up connections. It also helps when the server is down or rejects connections for any reason.
>
> Default: 120.0

So all the sessions in the pool are assigned to application transactions that take longer than 120 seconds, and a client session that is hanging in pgBouncer waiting for one of these transactions to finish gets disconnected.

The solution is to make sure that your database sessions are short and that the application doesn't forget to `COMMIT` when it is done with its work.

Comment: if query_timeout (query_wait_timeout)=0 , then also the same issue will occur ?? and how can we make our database sessions short from application point ?

Comment: `query_timeout` is 0 by default. You can only fix this in the application. Simply commit your transactions when you are done with your work.